# Using a single common WHERE condition for UNION in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT a.date AS EnrollDate, a.id, a.name, b.address FROM student a JOIN Location b ON a.id=b.id  
UNION  
SELECT a.date AS EnrollDate, a.id, a.name, b.address FROM teacher a JOIN Location b ON a.id=b.id  
WHERE a.date>'2010-01-01'  
ORDER BY EnrollDate
```

But the WHERE condition applies to the second SELECT statement only. I need to somehow apply to both the SELECT. The only option I have now is to apply WHERE condition individually. But I am working with several UNIONs and it is kind of tedious to include WHERE in all the places.
I was wondering if there is an easy way out.

By the way, I am working with MySQL.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a.date AS EnrollDate, a.id, a.name, b.address FROM student a 
    JOIN Location b ON a.id=b.id  
    UNION  
    SELECT a.date AS EnrollDate, a.id, a.name, b.address FROM teacher a 
    JOIN Location b ON a.id=b.id  
) A
WHERE EnrollDate > '2010-01-01'  
ORDER BY EnrollDate
```

This also has the advantage, compared to individual `ORDER BY`'s that the whole result is correctly ordered.

Comment: By the way, the WHERE clause should use EnrollDate instead of a.date for comparison ;)

Comment: Note that this (at least in my case) does not specify the conditions on the tables separately, it performs the where query on the whole result set, thus considering rows which are then thrown away. In my case (10M rows total) it not a solution to use it this way...

Comment: A decent database should push down the `EnrollDate` condition and not generate a huge intermediary result set. But you can of course manually add the where to both selects and just leave the `ORDER BY` to keep the whole result ordered.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a.date AS EnrollDate, a.id, a.name, b.address FROM student a 
    JOIN Location b ON a.id = b.id  
    UNION  
    SELECT a.date AS EnrollDate, a.id, a.name, b.address FROM teacher a 
    JOIN Location b ON a.id = b.id 
) A
WHERE a.date > '2010-01-01'  
ORDER BY EnrollDate
```

Comment: You have to either give the subquery an alias or replace the 'a.date' with simply 'date'.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way around it, you have to repeat the WHERE for each individual select clause.

Comment: Ok, looking at the other answers, my answer is wrong as it states there is no way around it. However, from a performance point of view, I would assume all the solutions of first UNIONing and then evaluating the WHERE condition will probably be worse (if you do not have a really clever optimizer, which I would not assume for MySql).

Comment: Applying the WHERE to each part individually is only better if there's an index available for it to use.  Also note that UNION is slower than UNION ALL, because it has the extra step of removing duplicates.